# MySQL - generating unique id like auto-increment

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

We have a table like this to maintain 'comments' for each 'article'. We have millions of articles and each articles may have multiple comments.

We require 'id' to be unique for each 'article' but not necessarily unique across all the articles.

In current approach, we do insert and then use mysql_insert_id() to get the 'id' and hence no additional query is required to get generated 'id'.

```
 CREATE TABLE `comments` (
   id bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   article int unsigned int default 0,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This approach works but it's an overkill in the sense that we need to use bigint for 'id' even though we don't expect comments per article to be more than a few thousands. We can maintain id manually but the downside is that it requires additional query to get 'id' which we get here just by calling mysql_insert_id(). This would have been easy if auto-increment of 'id' can be made within article scope.

Any suggestion on a better approach so that

1. we can generate a smaller 'id' which is unique for an article but not necessarily unique across all the article.
2. No additional query to get generated 'id'

Thanks

Comment: You can implement a sequence per article to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

> This approach works but it's an overkill in the sense that we need to
>   use bigint for 'id' even though we don't expect comments per article
>   to be more than a few thousands.

I do not think this is necessary true. Imagine that you want to output recent comments in some section of your application:

- with current design you display information and have links like `url/viewComment/commentId={commentId}`.
- if a comment is identifiable with `articleId` and `commentInternalId`, all urls would require both ids

One way to generate `id` is as (1 based):

```
(COUNT(1) FROM `comments` WHERE article = {article}) + 1
```

but it is clearly more complex and expensive that working with auto-increments.